# Не получается сделать анимацию выпадающего меню

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно создать красивую анимацию выпадающего меню.

1. После наведения курсора на фотографию появляется выпадающее меню. Фотография становится больше и вокруг нее появляется рамка. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: фотография. размер в пикселях: 1451x950]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    width: 244px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.myhover{

  width: 240px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0;

  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 16px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn"><img src="cake4.jpg" alt="" class="myhover"></button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 9px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem.</p>
  
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

без использования JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cat-image {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 8rem;
  padding: .1rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: inherit;
}

.dropdown {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 0fr;
  justify-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 12rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: .8rem;
  text-align: justify;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}

.dropdown:hover {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.dropdown:hover .cat-image {
  border-color: black;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.dropdown-content {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <img src="https://cataas.com/cat?type=small" alt="Random Cat" class="cat-image">
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Измените

```
.myhover{
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
}

.myhover:hover {
  width: 240px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 16px;
}
```